# reshape variable by unique values in each id

Tags: r, reshape, data-manipulation

Hi I've been trying to reshape my data to wide.

```
id story_id
1   123
1   123
1   123
1   123
2   213
2   213
2   213
3   123 
3   123
3   123
```

But all I get is:

```
id
1
2
3
```

I am using the code:

```
data=reshape(data, idvar="id", timevar="story_id", direction="wide")
```

The desired output is

```
id  story_id.123 story_id.213
1    123          NA
2    NA           213
3    123          NA
```

Please let me know what the problem is.

Comment: I have updated my question @MrFlick

Comment: wouldn't `table(unique(data))` be more desirable?  `reshape(unique(data)[, c(1,2,2)], timevar = 'story_id.1', v.names = 'story_id', dir = 'wide')` works also

Comment: @rawr -you can squash a bit more even `reshape(transform(unique(data), time=story_id), idvar="id", direction="wide")`

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
library(data.table) ; setDT(DF)

dcast(unique(DF), id ~ story_id, value.var = "story_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  distinct %>% 
  spread(story_id, story_id) %>% 
  setNames(., c(names(.)[1], paste0("story_id", names(.)[-1])))
#    id story_id123 story_id213
#1  1         123          NA
#2  2          NA         213
#3  3         123          NA
```